# Abbreviation for "Master?"

Tags: abbreviations

I know that Mr. is short for Mister and Mrs. is short for Mistress. Is there any comparable way to abbreviate "Master" that is distinguishable from Mister? Or would it just be Mr. again?

Comment: "Ms" is not short for "Miss".  "Ms" is used to indicate *either "Miss" or "Mrs" or a female of unspecified status.

Comment: Do you mean "Master" as referring to a young boy, or referring to a title such as "Master of Arts".  The former usage is not now common in BrE, and I can't remember how it was abbreviated when I was that age (too long ago!).  I suggest writing it in full.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I should think he would like to address the young man with a bit of respect in a formal latter.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I can only assume you didn't read *formal letter*. And I would guess by your user name you have less experience being addressed as a young man than I have. I got literally hundreds of letters with this mode of address. Mr. is obviously inappropriate. What would you put there if you were attempting to show manners as you might towards a young lady?

Comment: @Mari-LouA There are still literally hundreds of open listings for headmaster jobs if you do a google jobs search right now in my region. Where are you getting your information?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The correct answer already exists and I up-voted it. Would you like to defend your ridiculous assertion that the term Headmaster, which continues to be used by thousands of institutions, is outdated?

Comment: There is a basic misunderstanding here. And the question lacks clarity and context.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Master is certainly a common title in the US, for young boys. It may not be _pervasive_, but it is _common_, especially among older generations (70+).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some airlines' tickets/boarding-passes use MSTR, e.g. from [this travel website](http://www.citytravel-tour.com/CityTravelTour/content/airline-tickets) ...

> MISS = Girl under 12 years,
>   MSTR = Boy under 12years,
>   INF = Under 2 years.
>   Please advise in special request, if you have flexible date

**EDIT:**
At one time at least, according to Wikipedia:

> "Mstr" is [...] a prefix for boys on the UK Passport Service online application form. — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_(form_of_address))

... however when I checked the UK website today, its current online form has a selection option with **Master** rather than  **Mstr**! Note: the title does not appear on actual passport document, to avoid confusion I guess!

Update 13/Nov/2019: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149483/why-do-airline-tickets-have-titles-in-addition-to-names/149534#149534 which shows MSTR in use today on British Airways booking system.

Comment: "the title does not appear on actual passport document, to avoid confusion I guess": HM Passport office only prints professional or honorary titles such as Doctor or Professor or Sir in the passport (in full, not abbreviated), and only on the Official Observations page. Otherwise the title is omitted. If a person has a title and does not use his name (e.g., the Duke of Argyll), then only the title is printed.

Comment: If applying this to America, you should include our rules for using period after abbreviated words; the British do not include them in words where the end letter is included: Mstr. Inf. Miss (it is not short for mistress, just derived from it).

Comment: MSTR seems preferable to the 'M' abbreviation of the AHD cited in another answer

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest, ***M.*** (to be distinguished from [***M***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/M), which stands for [*Monsieur*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Monsieur))

> Master
>
> *Abbr.* M.
>
> a. Used formerly as a title for a man holding a naval office ranking next below a lieutenant on a warship.
>
> b. Used as a title for a man who serves as the head or presiding officer of certain societies, clubs, orders, or institutions.
>
> c. Used as a title for any of various male officers having specified duties concerning the management of the British royal household.
>
> d. **Used as a courtesy title before the given or full name of a boy not considered old enough to be addressed as *Mister***.
>
> e. *Archaic* Used as a form of address for a man; mister.
>
> [American Heritage® Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Master&submit.x=52&submit.y=19)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not referring to an academic "Master" of some sort, but rather the honorific you might apply to a child before they turn 18 and gain the Mr. or Miss/Ms./Mrs. title, *Master* should be used in its entirety without abbreviation.

Comment: This is a comment (with which I agree) but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Mazura How is it not an answer? The OP asks for an abbreviation, and this answer says there isn't one. That's a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @Mitch - It doesn't say there isn't one. It says you *shouldn't* use it; without citing a manual of style.